# Matlab and Complex Number Computing

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, complex-numbers, matlab-cvst

I am currently writing a code in matlab to analyze the optical flow in leach hearts and for some reason, whenever I run this it returns weird complex functions. I'm not sure where they come from and I would love some help on figuring that out.

```
function [opticalFlow] = opticalflowanalysis(handles,hOpticalflow)

videoReader = vision.VideoFileReader('jun07_0165_segment8to12_20.avi','ImageColorSpace','Intensity','VideoOutputDataType','single');
converter = vision.ImageDataTypeConverter; 
opticalFlow = vision.OpticalFlow('OutputValue', 'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form','ReferenceFrameDelay', 6);
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Lines','BorderColor','Custom', 'CustomBorderColor', 255);
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Name','Motion Vector');
%Convert the image to single precision, then compute optical flow for the video. Generate coordinate points and draw lines to indicate flow. 

i=0;
mm = ones(1080,1920);
%Display results.      
while ~isDone(videoReader)
    frame = step(videoReader);
    im = step(converter, frame);
    of = step(opticalFlow, im); %always complex number
    aa = size(of)
    lines = videooptflowlines(of, 5); %complex number only sometimes - when lines appear?
    bb = size(lines)
    x = i+ 1;
    if(x==2)
        mm = of;
    end
    % show diff bw of and lines matrices
    if (x == 2)||(x == 10)
        for j=1:1:1080 %gives j = [1 2 ... 720]
            for k=1:1:1920 %gives k = [1 2 ... 1280]
                of(j,k)
                lines(j,k)
                if(of(j,k) ~= lines(j,k))
                    disp(['of[',num2str(j),',',num2str(k),'] = ', num2str(of(j,k)), '...', 'lines[',num2str(j),',',num2str(k),'] = ', num2str(lines(j,k))])
                end
            end
        end
    end
    if ~isempty(lines)
      out =  step(shapeInserter, im, lines); 
      step(videoPlayer, out);
    end
end
%Close the video reader and player ,
%handles.output = hObject;
release(videoPlayer);
release(videoReader);

mm
```

It returns:

```
aa =

        1080        1920


bb =

       36465           4
```

Where do the variables from bb come from?

Thanks,
Jacob

Comment: You're saying that the variable `lines` is sometimes complex, but it shouldn't be? Looking at the contents of `videooptflowlines` (`edit videooptflowlines` in the command window) in R2012b, I don't see how it could ever return complex values.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question actually has nothing to do with complex numbers at all. I think the title and tags should be edited to reflect this, but would like further clarification from the OP before going ahead with an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting semi-colons (*ie* `;`) at the ends of the lines in which `aa` and `bb` are assigned to

```
aa = size(of);
...
bb = size(lines);
```

and see what happens.

Mind you, since neither `aa` nor `bb` seems to be used later in the program you could probably safely delete both those lines.

Comment: I agree, this seems to be entirely due to suppression of output, and nothing at all with complex numbers.

Comment: I've left the semi-colons off on purpose because I don't want those specific outputs to be suppressed. I'm just confused as to where the output from "variable bb" is coming from, I see no correlation between it and the inputs.